# How to get value from span with selenium in python?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, bots, instagram

Can't get value out of these elements.
Also there doesn't seem to be any unique identifiers for these elements, just wondering how you would work around this.

I've tried getting the element by xpath and parsing with .text with no luck.
Is there any difference between the xpath and full xpath?

Thanks for the help,

```
[](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xFqlu.png)
[](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjUoq.png)
[](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ltGL0.png)
```

Comment: wow this messed up, sorry.

Comment: if you hit `ctrl+f` on the element inspector in the devtools, you can use xpath and css selectors directly to see if they would grab that element. In your case I would try to find a consistent id or css element path to grab this item

ie. `*#userData li:nth-child(4) > span`

Then in selenium you would use `driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '*#userData li:nth-child(4) > span').text`

Comment: @DiegoCuadros thanks for the help, but im getting an error with every selector I use. 
postCount = self.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#mount_0_0_0l > div > div > div.x9f619.x1n2onr6.x1ja2u2z > div > div > div > div.x78zum5.xdt5ytf.x1t2pt76.x1n2onr6.x1ja2u2z.x10cihs4 > div.x9f619.xvbhtw8.x78zum5.x168nmei.x13lgxp2.x5pf9jr.xo71vjh.x1uhb9sk.x1plvlek.xryxfnj.x1c4vz4f.x2lah0s.x1q0g3np.xqjyukv.x1qjc9v5.x1oa3qoh.x1qughib > div.x1gryazu.xh8yej3.x10o80wk.x14k21rp.x17snn68.x6osk4m.x1porb0y > div:nth-child(2) > section > main > div > header > section > ul > li:nth-child(1) > span")

Comment: @DiegoCuadros this is the error: return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {"using": by, "value": value})["value"]. If you dont mind further elaborating on your method, i would really appreciate the explanation.

Comment: you need to test this selector yourself in the browser and make sure it consistently locates the element you want. I'm assuming you're not very familiar with css selectors or modern web development, because your selectors are way too big and those classes look like they are randomly generated by whatever server is hosting the site. Look up CSS Selector rules to help make this way easier. You're going to find that there might be an id on some element or a specific css path that always gets to the element you want. Test it in the devtools of the browser. Edit your question with an update